# Finding the value of C in probability density function

Tags: probability, integration

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} cx  & : 0\leq x\leq 1/2 \\ c(1-x) & : 1/2 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 &: \textsf{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Is $\int_0^{1/2}cx\,dx + \int_{1/2}^1c(1-x)\,dx = 1$ the correct approach to finding the value of $c$?

Comment: You have overlap in your definition of $x$, should the first one be to $0 \le x \le 1/2$. When that's fixed and you change the corresponding limit, the approach looks fine.

Comment: @Gregory sorry, it was a typo. Thanks for the quick response. I was not able to find anything like it here on stack, with the 2 "equations" as cases (I don't know the right word for it since English isn't my first language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.
$$\int_0^{1/2}cx\,dx + \int_{1/2}^1c(1-x)\,dx = 1$$
So you get,
$$\left [  \frac{cx^{2}}{2}\right ]_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left [  cx-\frac{cx^{2}}{2}\right ]_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}=1$$
$$(\frac{c}{8}-0)+(c-\frac{c}{2}-\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c}{8})=1$$
$$\frac{c}{4}=1$$
$$c=4$$